# how search in wikipedia works?

Tags: search, data-structures, webserver, wikipedia

I am a beginer in web technologies so sry if its a lame question.

Wikipedia and other such sites which host million of web pages. How search works in these pages. Do they store all html pages in memory? if yes What are the possible data structure used to store all the html pages to store in-memory and do search among those so fast?

Answer (score 3):

Wikipedia uses the [Lucene](http://lucene.apache.org/java/docs/index.html) full text search engine. Another popular full text search engine is [Sphinx](http://sphinxsearch.com/).

Answer (score 3):

They have quite detailed descriptions of what [exactly they got](http://meta.wikimedia.org/wiki/Wikimedia_servers).

Answer (score 0):

[Wikipedia: Web search](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Web_search_engine)
[How Internet Search Engines Work](http://computer.howstuffworks.com/internet/basics/search-engine.htm)
[How Search Engines Work](http://www.monash.com/spidap4.html) (rather nice explanation)